# singular vs plural : role and responsibility or roles and responsibilities

Tags: singular-vs-plural

1. Customer focus is at the heart of everything we do, regardless of our **roles and responsibilities**.
2. Customer focus is at the heart of everything we do, regardless of our **role and responsibility**.

Which should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

I think  the answer depends on whether you are talking about the same role or different ones.

Let's assume "our" is the possessive pronoun for the members of a team. If all members perform the same role and the responsibility (they all have the role X and the responsibility Y), then use **role and responsibility**.

If each member has a different role and responsibility (role X and responsibility Y for member 1, role X and responsibility Z for member 2 and ...), then use **roles and responsibilities**.

Comment: In the singular case, it would also make it sound more idiomatic (and less like a mistake in grammar) if it were phrased as *our* ***shared*** *role and responsibility*. The use of **shared** makes the meaning explicit.

Comment: shoud we put a before role and responsiblity, since they are singular?

Comment: @YongxueLaw No, you can't use "our" and "a" together, but as Jason mentioned, using a word like ***shared*** before *role and responsibility* would make your sentence sound more idiomatic.

Comment: How about: Customer focus is at the heart of everything we do, regardless of role and responsibility.

Comment: @YongxueLaw Well, I think it's incorrect. In most cases a singular countable noun (like role) should be preceded by a determiner such as *a*, *the*, *this*, *our*, *etc*.